# YII2 исключение ForbiddenHttpException

Tags: php, yii2, yii

При обращении post запросом к actionAnswerTest происходит следующая ошибка:

> [error] 6754#6754: *479979 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: An Error 
>      occurred while handling another error:
>      exception 'yii\web\ForbiddenHttpException' with message 'Вам не разрешено 
>      производить данное действие.

Настройка правил в контроллере:

```
 public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'actions' => ['index', 'partial', 'complete', 'answer', 'answer-test'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                ],
            ],
            'denyCallback' => function($rule, $action) {
                return Yii::$app->getResponse()->redirect('denied')->send();
            },
        ],
        'verbs' => [
            'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
            'actions' => [
                'update' => ['post'],
                'test-partial' => ['post'],
                'test-complete' => ['post'],
                'test-answer' => ['post'],
            ],
        ],
        [
            'class' => ContentNegotiator::className(),
            'only' => ['update', 'answer'],
            'formats' => [
                'application/json' => Response::FORMAT_JSON,
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

Запрос посылается авторизованным пользователем.

Answer (score 0):

Решается переименованием `actionAnswerTest` в `actionAnswertes`, и заменой `answer-test` на `answertest`